# I don't have an acess to other browsers except Chrome and Electron

Tags: cypress

I tried to add some other browsers but for some reason it's not visible. Only Chrome and Electron is available. Maybe anyone had the same prolem and know how to add for example firefox broswer?
I am not sure maybe I did some mistakes while adding them, but I tried a few times and it didn't work.
I will appreciate any suggestions :)
[image]

Comment: Access to other browsers where? How this is programming question?

Comment: Presume you have Cypress version > 4?

Comment: @SteveZodiac yes it's the latest version 6.3.0

Comment: You can check the list of browsers Cypress tests against vs your own browser installation here [Windows](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/develop/packages/launcher/__snapshots__/windows_spec.ts.js) or here [Mac](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/develop/packages/launcher/__snapshots__/darwin_spec.ts.js)

Comment: Also try installing a new one, say [Firefox Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/) and see if it turns up in Cypress.

Answer (score 2):

Cypress has very strict browser detection rules. On Windows (Assuming you are using win10 based on that screenshot), it looks for browser binary in `Program Files` and `Program Files (x86)`.

Source: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/develop/packages/launcher/lib/windows/index.ts#L41

If for some reason you installed Firefox in some other folder, it is possible that Cypress fails to automatically detect that browser. In such cases, `--browser` key comes in handy.

Get the path for your firefox.exe (How I do it: Go to properties on your firefox shortcut and copy the value in the target field) and pass it as an arg to your cypress open/run command like this

```
cypress open --browser "C:\\Path\Foo\\Bar\\firefox.exe"
```

Cypress will list the browser from the given path as Custom Firefox Browser.

Link to Doc: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/launching-browsers.html#Launching-by-a-path

There are some issues with `--browser` on windows, like, it cannot open edge and fails to open chrome with multiple escape backslashes but should work fine for firefox.

Answer (score 0):

1.This is from the [cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/cross-browser-testing.html):

> Excluding Electron, any browser you want to run Cypress tests in needs
> to be installed on your local system or CI environment. A full list of
> detected browsers is displayed within the browser selection menu of
> the Test Runner.

So to see Firefox in your browsers list you have install Firefox on your local system.

2.Also, this is the list of browsers that cypress currently supports([cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/launching-browsers.html#Browsers)):

- Canary
- Chrome
- Chromium
- Edge
- Edge Beta
- Edge Canary
- Edge Dev
- Electron
- Firefox
- Firefox Developer Edition
- Firefox Nightly

3.The “browser” argument can be set to chrome, chromium, edge, electron, firefox to launch a browser detected on your system. Cypress will attempt to automatically find the installed browser for you.

```
npm cypress run --browser firefox
```

4.You can launch any supported browser by specifying a path to the binary:

```
npm cypress open --browser /usr/bin/chromium
npm cypress run--browser /usr/bin/chromium
```

Comment: Thank u very much for your answer! But Chrome, Firefox and Edge are for example installed on my computer, but only Chrome is visible in this list. But the other are not visible for some reasons.

Comment: @PolinaLisetska I updated my answer, you can try point 3 and 4 if that works for you.